# Not enough GPU memory when training small model (< 100 mb) in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

Training small model (< 100 mb) in tensorflow always use too much GPU memory ,why?   How to figure it out?

Comment: decrease batch size and use timeline to see where memory is going (tl.generate_chrome_trace_format(show_memory=True..))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default tensorflow can grow up to totality of all GPU memory. 
You can restrict it by setting config for a Session:

```
gpu_memory_fraction = 0.4 # Fraction of GPU memory to use
config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=
                       tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=gpu_memory_fraction))                          
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```